# How do I extend a class method to surround it in a try..catch without changing implementation in consuming code?

Tags: python

I am using a package which provides a class whose methods make an external call and throws an exception if conditions are not met. This is widely consumed in code I do not own and cannot modify. I would like to somehow capture the exception, perform an action, and retry the original call. The code I do own however is instantiating the class as a singleton to be shared by the rest of the code.

The package (uneditable)

```
class A:
    def doaction():
        try:
            action() # external service call which raises exception if conditions are not met
        except:
            raise Exception
    
    def doaction_a():
        return doaction()

    def doaction_b():
        return doaction()
...
```

Consumer (uneditable)

```
class consumer():
    def failing():
        client.doaction()
```

My code (where the fix will be, hopefully)

```
def setup_connection():
    auth = generate_key()
    client = A(auth) # client is now available for consumer to access
```

Apologies if this is something absurd, I am open to suggestions. The goal is to capture the exception, fix the conditions which made it so, and retry the action without modifying the package nor the consumer codebase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a child class that overrides the method and catches the exception.

```
define myA(A):

    def doaction(self, *args, **kwargs):
        while True:
            try:
                super().doaction(self, *args, **kwargs)
                break
            except Exception:
                # fix conditions
```

Then instantiate this class in your code instead of `A`.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to extend the class:

```
class B(A):
    def do_action():
        try:
            super().do_action()
        except Exception:
            # log it or whatever
```

Now just create an instance of `B` as your singleton.